# Optimize/simplify this SQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this query and it works, but I know this can be simplified:

```
SELECT class, COUNT(class), publisher FROM books WHERE publisher = 'Company ABC' GROUP BY class
UNION
SELECT class, COUNT(class), publisher FROM books WHERE publisher = 'Company DEF' GROUP BY class
UNION
SELECT class, COUNT(class), publisher FROM books WHERE publisher = 'Company GHI' GROUP BY class
UNION
SELECT class, COUNT(class), publisher FROM books WHERE publisher = 'Company JKL' GROUP BY class
UNION
SELECT class, COUNT(class), publisher FROM books WHERE publisher = 'Company MNO' GROUP BY class;
```

It also hard-coded but I really want for the query to look for distinct companies in the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT publisher FROM books;
```

Result:

```
publisher
Company ABC
Company DEF
Company GHI
Company JKL
Company MNO
```

Comment: Give us some sample data.

Comment: `GROUP BY class, publisher`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  Your DBMS should reject it with an error.  You say it "works", so I guess it's doing what you want, but I'm not sure I can advise you on how to improve it.

The basic problem is

```
SELECT class,
       COUNT(class) as N,
       publisher
FROM books
GROUP BY class
```

With an aggregate (`COUNT`), the `GROUP BY` clause must include every non-aggregate in the `SELECT` clause.  In your case, it must say

```
GROUP BY class, publisher
```

If you say only `GROUP BY class`, what does the count represent?  My hope is that the DBMS is being a little be "smart": in your query, `publisher` is a single value, so `COUNT` is the number of non-NULL `class` values per class for that publisher.  That is the equivalent of

```
SELECT class,
       COUNT(class) as N,
       publisher
FROM books
WHERE publisher in (
      'Company ABC', 'Company DEF', 'Company GHI',
  'Company JKL', 'Company MNO'
  )
GROUP BY class, publisher
;
```

If that does what you want, it's definitely an improvement.  It's standard SQL, and will almost certainly execute faster.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and optimizing my query. Can I add a subquery in IN clause like this `SELECT DISTINCT publisher FROM books`?

Comment: Yes, you can.  No need for `DISTINCT` with `IN`, though.  Logically it's unnecessary, and your DBMS may well perform better without it.

Comment: Great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
SELECT class, COUNT(class), publisher 
FROM books 
GROUP BY class,publisher
```